# How do I travel on a return flight with a different passport from my outgoing flight?

Tags: air-travel, passports

When I buy a plane ticket, I need to give my passport details.

If the flight is to my home country, where I will renew my passport and get a new passport with a different number, do I need to do anything extra to take the return flight?

Can I just bring the old passport along?

Comment: Have you considered calling the airline?

Comment: Yes call the airline and tell them about the situation. You might be in a position to update your passport records on the booking via their website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have your new passport, call the airline and ask them to update your passport details. They will likely want you verify your old pp number and/or perhaps the payment card number, so have them handy when you call.

Just to be safe, I would carry the old one with you when you fly.